# ASP.NET GridView Custom Binding Error

Tags: .net, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I was given the task of designing a ORM + Object Model for our product. It has primarily been used for Windows + WinForms development but it is now needing to be used with our ASP.NET products as well.

However there seems to be a problem with binding the Collection object to a GridView (and I suspect other ASP.NET data source controls).

The online dev team get the following error

`[HttpException (0x80004005): The IListSource does not contain a data source named ''.  Check your DataMember value.]`

The collection object we use uses a 'view' collection to handle sorting / filtering (similar to how a DataView relates to a DataTable) and this is the 'List' that the IListSource implementation returns. But for some reason the ASP.NET control isn't happy with it and throws an exception.

If I use the Linq extension method 'ToList' on the collection, it binds successfully - but converting a list to a list seems pretty pointless and as the GridView binds to DataTables which also implement IListSource it must be something I've done wrong in the object model.

But I'm a bit lost as to where to look, it seems most of the google examples show binding to a dataset so not particularly helpful.

As always, any insights welcomed.

edit

---

AlumniShopItems is of type:

`DataObjectCollection<AlumniShopItem>`

which is a subclass of:

`DataObjectCollection<T> : BindingList<T>, IListSource, IList<T>, IDataObjectCollection, IFillableList where T : DataObject`

IListSource returns the following typed list: `ObjectListView<T>`

which intern implements the following interfaces:

`IBindingListView, IList<T>, ITypedList, IRaiseItemChangedEvents, ICancelAddNew, IDeserializationCallback`

---

Thanks

Marlon

Below is the code they're using:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="ShopGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
                        OnRowEditing="ShopGrid_RowEditing" 
              OnRowUpdating="ShopGrid_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit" 
              OnRowDataBound="RowBinding" >
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Ident")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Ident")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Name" >
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="NameText" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pay Pal ID" >
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="PayPalText" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("PayPalID")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="PayPalLabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("PayPalID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" >
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="PhotoPath" runat="server" Text="" > </asp:TextBox>
                                     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                     <asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="itemPhoto" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price" >
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%#Bind("Current")%>' Enabled="true" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%#Bind("Current")%>' Enabled="false" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Somewhere in page load:

```
Line 57:                 alumniShopItems.FillMe();
Line 58:                 ShopGrid.DataSource = alumniShopItems;
Line 59:                 ShopGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: what happen inside "FillMe()"?

Comment: Does your DataSource Return Null values as Empty Strings?

Comment: what is the type of `alumniShopItems`? and its bases classes and interfaces if any

Comment: "FillMe()" goes to the database, for each row it finds it populates an object and adds it to the collection. As for returning null values, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but no they'll be null.

Comment: type info for alumniShopItems is now included in edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted this, so I'm going to put the answer here in case anyone else ever experiences this issue.

It was due to the fact the IListSource.ContainsListCollection property was returning true (my fault, I misunderstood what it was trying to do), changing this so it returned false sorted it.

Oddly the WinForms binding behaviour had worked fine like this which is why it hadn't been a problem before, changing it so it returned false hasn't affected it working on windows either.

Reason I was confused is originally I thought the ContainsListCollection property was informing the control that the list had another list that it wanted it to use. Now I can see this functionality is achieved just by implementing the interface (which I agree makes perfect sense) and the property is specifying whether or not the returned IList has a subcollection within it and to use that instead.

All I can say is thank god for .NET source stepping! despite having to do it in a VM because I installed Windows 7 SP1...